# Is it safe to assign bool or float to int32_t?

Tags: c++, int32

I have a `c++` project that have a struct with `int32_t` member data type and i want to assign `bool` and `float` variables to it, will that ruin the value of the variable? If yes, what should i do other than changing the struct member data type?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "safe", `float` will be truncated to `int`, but it depends on you if that is safe or not.

Comment: You can definitely *convert* `bool` to `int32_t` and `float` to `int32_t` but the difference is that second conversion can lead to data loss which is program defect.

Comment: If your float value is 1.234, what do you expect to happen when you assign it to an int, that can only store integral values?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the compiler has to use a value of a type in a context where another type is expected, an implicit conversion is performed.

The rules for implicit conversions are [numerous](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), but under Floating–integral conversions, there is the following paragraph:

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any
>   integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the
>   fractional part is discarded. If the value cannot fit into the
>   destination type, the behavior is undefined (even when the destination
>   type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply). If the
>   destination type is bool, this is a boolean conversion (see below).

So, you can safely assign a floating point type (e.g. `float` or `double`) to an integer. Provided that the value can fit, the decimal part will be truncated. This implies a loss of data, and might be a source of bugs, or might be done on purpose in certain applications. Note that the floating point types have a larger range than `int32_t`, and if the value cannot be stored, it is undefined behaviour as per the standard.

Bools, on the other hand, can be safely assigned to integer types under all circumstances:

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type
>   (note that if the destination type is int, this is an integer
>   promotion, not an integer conversion).

Answer (score 0):

The value you assign will be converted to `int32_t`. The `bool` value will not lose anything. The `float` value will be truncated. Only the integral part of it will be stored.

> If yes, what should i do other than changing the struct member data type?

That depends on whether the type of the values you want to store are determined at runtime or compile-time. If it's determined at runtime, you can use an [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead of an `int32_t`:

```
#include <any>

struct MyStruct {
    std::any val;
};

// ...

MyStruct s;
s.val = true; // val now contains a bool
s.val = 3.1415; // val now contains a double
s.val = 3.1415f; // val now contains a float
s.val = 42; // val now contains an int
```

If the type is determined at compile-time, you can make a struct template:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct {
    T val;
};

// ...

MyStruct<bool> s1;
s1 = false;

MyStruct<float> s2;
s2 = 3.1415;
```